# How to Optimize 3d Array Lookup

Tags: c, optimization, multidimensional-array, compiler-optimization

new to stack overflow. I am working to speed up a method that I have to mask certain elements in a 3d array. My code as it is is as followed:

```
for (i = 1; i < height-1; i++)
for (j = 1; j < width-1; j++)
  {
    tmp = 
          mask[1][0]*a[i][j-1][0]+
          mask[0][1]*a[i-1][j][0]+
          mask[1][1]*a[i][j][0]+
          mask[2][1]*a[i+1][j][0]+
          mask[1][2]*a[i][j+1][0];
    if (tmp>255)
          tmp = 255;
    else if (tmp<0)
          tmp = 0;
    c[i][j][0] = tmp;
    tmp = 
          mask[1][0]*a[i][j-1][1]+
          mask[0][1]*a[i-1][j][1]+
          mask[1][1]*a[i][j][1]+
          mask[2][1]*a[i+1][j][1]+
          mask[1][2]*a[i][j+1][1];
    if (tmp>255)
          tmp = 255;
    else if (tmp<0)
          tmp = 0;
    c[i][j][1] = tmp;
    tmp = 
          mask[1][0]*a[i][j-1][2]+
          mask[0][1]*a[i-1][j][2]+
          mask[1][1]*a[i][j][2]+
          mask[2][1]*a[i+1][j][2]+
          mask[1][2]*a[i][j+1][2];
    if (tmp>255)
          tmp = 255;
    else if (tmp<0)
          tmp = 0;
    c[i][j][2] = tmp;
  }
```

I have already made some optimizations by unrolling my outer for loop, however I need to make it faster. I know there must be a way to use pointers to access the 3d memory addresses in a more efficient way, however I do not have the level of C expertise to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Is this area _really_ the trouble spot?

Comment: Also: is it possible to modify your question to include a minimum working example with synthetic data that mimics your problem?

Comment: Also, [this](https://github.com/flame/how-to-optimize-gemm/wiki#blocking-to-maintain-performance) might be useful.

Comment: If you are looking for (slightly) faster memory access with pointers, you can track pointers and perform pointer arithmetic. E.g. with `int *aPtr = &a[i][j]` you can jump to `&a[i][j+1]` with `aPtr + 1`, and to `&a[i+1][j]` with `aPtr+width`. But as Richard mentioned, you should make sure that such optimizations are really worth the effort.

Comment: Yes, my task is to speed up this particular piece of code myself without compiler optimization. There is definitely a more efficient way of looking up the array elements, I am just not sure how. And I don't believe I can quite get a minimum working example going. The question is more so how to optimize 3d array lookups in this fashion

Comment: @HenningKoehler how does this work with 3d arrays though? I understand the concept you stated with 2d arrays, but for 3d arrays how can I do this?

Comment: E.g. if you have `int a[2][3][4]; int *aPtr = &a[0][0][0]`, then you have equalities `aPtr + 1 == &a[0][0][1]`, `aPtr+4 == &a[0][1][0]` (since the innermost array has 4 elements), and `aPtr+12 == &a[1][0][0]` (since each inner 2D array contains 3*4 elements).

Comment: Still wondering about that minimal, working example. It would, for instance, help clarify what the datatype of `a` and `mask` are, as well as the values of mask.

Comment: The problem here seems to be having constructed such a complex data structure to begin with. Smells like some math person taking decisions instead of a programmer, which is always a bad idea. How to un-crap it is anyone's guess, as we don't know what this is or how it works. The key to optimizing it is to make accesses cache-friendly, and in order to do that, you must know the nature of the data.

Comment: @Lundin: It's not too exotic: it's a weighted, clipped [stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_code) operation on an RGB image expressed as three-dimensional array. But knowing the data types and mask values would be useful for optimization.

Comment: @Richard If you say so, but in that case I am right. Because then it should have been implemented as an array of struct instead, so that when you access the 3 colors, you access adjacent memory cells instead of wildly different ones. Arrays in C are low-level and directly mapped to adjacent memory. Attempting to use the array dimensions for some higher-level concept might give inefficient code.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce another loop `k` to reduce the usage of `tmp` 3 times.

```
for (i = 1; i < height-1; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < width-1; j++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<3; k++)
        {
            tmp = 
                mask[1][0]*a[i][j-1][k]+
                mask[0][1]*a[i-1][j][k]+
                mask[1][1]*a[i][j][k]+
                mask[2][1]*a[i+1][j][k]+
                mask[1][2]*a[i][j+1][k];
            if (tmp>255)
                tmp = 255;
            else if (tmp<0)
                tmp = 0;
            c[i][j][k] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

You are using `mask[1][0]`, `[0][1]` and `[1][1]`, but are not using `[1][0]` and `[2][0]`. So cannot simplify it further.

Comment: This actually performs worse than "unrolling" the k loop like I did in my program description. I am not going for readable or logical code but strictly compiler optimization

Comment: There is always a benefit in making the code more readable and more maintainable. You can avoid errors in coding in current use and future enhancements. You need to investigate whether you really need to improve run time for this part of the code, or whether the job can be done by using compiler optimization.

Comment: @P.Programming You should always go for readable and logical code. In most cases the compiler will do a better job in optimizing the code than you ever will, and the compiler usually works better with simple, logical code.